# EC2 Instance not allowing me to ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I had a running EC2 Instance and it was working fine, then all of a sudden I couldn't ssh into it. I went into aws console, and couldn't ssh in with the connect button. I ran this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-awssupport-troubleshootssh.html

and it failed. I then rebuilt another EC2 instance and the same thing happened again. I don't have Amazon support and I don't know how to debug this. Anyone have any ideas. I am running the following instance `Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-0a63f96e85105c6d3 (64-bit x86) / ami-0f330b426f35ac7f4 (64-bit Arm)`

Any debugging help would be great. I am reluctant to just build another instance and have the same thing happen. I never had this issue before and dont think I have changed anything in my workflow

Update #1
To start here is my security groups
[image]

here is my instance screenshot
[image]

Comment: You haven't really given us enough information to help you. You're basically saying that you create an instance and cn SSH in and then some time later (minutes, hours, days, weeks?) later it stops working? Is it still responding to other protocols? You need to do troubleshooting, starting with security groups, NACLs, keys, check the instance screenshot. Have it upload the OS and key logs to CloudWatch logs when you first it up so you can see what is going on, using the Cloudwatch Logs agent. Mount the volume as a data volume if you need to look the logs.

Comment: ok well this is exactly the debuggin info I need. I did check the security groups. I'll post some more info.

Comment: I added my security groups above. What do I check for NACLs, if it is my keys why can't I connect from the connect button in aws console. I will add the instance screenshot. How do I upload the os ket logs to cloud watch logs. I have to go for now. I will come back to this thanks for the help so far.

Comment: The console has three options for connecting to an EC2 instance, you need to be more precise with what you're doing. You should be using a standalone SSH client or session manager, but session manager is quite tricky to get working as it relies on comms to AWS infrastructure, either over the internet or vpc endpoints. You can use VPC flow logs to diagnose what's going wrong here. Google something like "upload ec2 instance logs to cloudwatch logs" for instructions. AWS is a complex enterprise platform, training is really required to use it effectively.

Comment: Thanks for all your help tim, I will do some googling on all the things you instructed. I might switch over to something like digital ocean or upcloud for this project. Again thanks

Comment: AWS is great, but complex. If all you need is a basic server then Digital Ocean can be a better choice, and significantly cheaper. This will be something you've not quite configured right, most likely in the instance, as the behaviour you've described is unlikely to be AWS.